# Not able to get unique response from a factory method called in two different controllers

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to call a factory to generate token from two different controllers
1.homeCtrl
2.savingsCtrl
but m getting same token value in both places

here is my code

---factory

```
app.factory('tokenFactory', ['$http', function($http) { 
   return $http({
          method: 'POST', 
          url: "../api/v1/getToken", 
          headers : {
                    'Content-Type':'application/json',
                    'X-API-KEY':'04g4g00c04ks4sokgkoosg0kwww0cww4www0kc80',
                    'Authorization':"Basic cGVzYXZlQXBwOkNDNTVzV0FwUW0zYWxpazlLNTcwTTFXQ1RNOUJ1TmZS"
                },
          data: {"grant_type":"client_credentials"}
        })   .success(function(data) { 
              return data; 
            }) 
            .error(function(err) { 
              return err; 
            }); 
}]);
```

----homeCtrl

```
app.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope','tokenFactory', function($scope,tokenFactory){

  tokenFactory.success(function(data) {

    $scope.token = data;
    var token=data.access_token;
}])
```

----savingsCtrl

```
app.controller('savingsCtrl', ['$scope','tokenFactory','savingsFactory', function($scope,tokenFactory,savingsFactory){

  tokenFactory.success(function(data) {
    $scope.token = data;
    var token=data.access_token;
    var userId='9c28735e-8a29-401d-b94e-6cc90a087d96';
    alert(token)
    $scope.getGoals=function(){

        savingsFactory.getGoals(userId,token).success(function(data) {
        $scope.goals = data;
            var goal=$scope.goals.goalName;
            alert(goal)
      });
    }
```

Comment: The .success and .error part must not be in the factory. Callbacks should be placed in controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You should return the $http with some method not directly in factory

```
 app.factory('tokenFactory', ['$http', function($http) { 
    var getToken = function(){
      return $http({
      method: 'POST', 
      url: "../api/v1/getToken", 
      headers : {
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'X-API-KEY':'04g4g00c04ks4sokgkoosg0kwww0cww4www0kc80',
                'Authorization':"Basic cGVzYXZlQXBwOkNDNTVzV0FwUW0zYWxpazlLNTcwTTFXQ1RNOUJ1TmZS"
            },
      data: {"grant_type":"client_credentials"}
    })   .success(function(data) { 
          return data; 
        }) 
        .error(function(err) { 
          return err; 
        }); 
   }
return {
     getToken : getToken
   }
```

}]);

and then use it in controllers like this

```
  tokenFactory.getToken().then(function (data) {

            $scope.token = data.data.access_token;
            var token = data.data.access_token;
            alert(token);
        });
```

I have tested this and its working

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

----factory

```
    app.factory('tokenFactory', ['$http', function($http) { 
        function getToken() {
            $http({
              method: 'POST', 
              url: "../api/v1/getToken", 
              headers : {
                        'Content-Type':'application/json',
                        'X-API-KEY':'04g4g00c04ks4sokgkoosg0kwww0cww4www0kc80',
                        'Authorization':"Basic cGVzYXZlQXBwOkNDNTVzV0FwUW0zYWxpazlLNTcwTTFXQ1RNOUJ1TmZS"
                    },
              data: {"grant_type":"client_credentials"}
            })
        }

        return {getToken: getToken}
    }]);
```

----homeCtrl

```
    app.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope','tokenFactory', function($scope,tokenFactory){

      tokenFactory.getToken()

      .success(function(data) {

          $scope.token = data;
          var token=data.access_token;
      }
    }])
```

----savingsCtrl

```
    app.controller('savingsCtrl', ['$scope','tokenFactory','savingsFactory', function($scope,tokenFactory,savingsFactory){

      tokenFactory.getToken()

      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.token = data;
        var token=data.access_token;
        var userId='9c28735e-8a29-401d-b94e-6cc90a087d96';
        alert(token)
        $scope.getGoals=function(){

            savingsFactory.getGoals(userId,token).success(function(data) {
            $scope.goals = data;
                var goal=$scope.goals.goalName;
                alert(goal)
          });
        }
    }])
```

Comment: removed the sucess and error methods from factory...still not giivng unique tokens

Comment: For each post, the route "../api/v1/getToken" is supposed to be returning different tokens; maybe it's a server-side problem.

Test it using Postman.

Comment: And for your factory, best practice is to return an object rather than the function directly (in case you've multiple functions in one factory, which is always more likely to occur). CODE UPDATED.

Comment: @Ramising Nadeem, this is the solution purposed in my ansewer this way it works fine, instead of returning $http, Rutuja Kurle should return object which returns a function, and calling that function will return different tokens

Comment: Although not a clean code, the way he did it (returning $http directly, but without the .success and .error) should work; I did not test it though. tokenFactory() should trigger the $http function; don't think that's the error.